# Как передать делегат, проигнорировав его аргументы?

Tags: c#, делегаты

Допустим, я хочу сделать запись в консоль без передачи аргументов в метод. Возможно ли это как-нибудь сделать?

```
public static void Test(Action<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int> runAfterwork)
    {
        runAfterwork(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(/*Хочу вызвать Console.WriteLine("smth")*/);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы определили для метода `Test` параметр `Action`, который сам принимает восемь параметров. Следовательно, при вызове нужно указать именно такой делегат - с восемью параметрами.

```
Test((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) => Console.WriteLine("smth"));
```

В теле делегата - `Console.WriteLine("smth")` - аргументы игнорируются, никак не используются.

Можно делегат создать заранее и далее использовать его:

```
Action<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int> action = (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8) => Console.WriteLine("smth");

Test(action);
```

---

В C# есть такое понятие: [Discards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) - явное указание, что значение отбрасывается, не используется. Возможно, вам нужно именно это.

```
(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => Console.WriteLine("smth")
```

Comment: @thepotion33 - вы вполне можете оформить свой ответ. Оно того стоит. Или хотя бы перенесите свой вариант в вопрос и спросите, как оно работает.